# Timeout error when post public key string with URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

I am creating a rsa key pair and send the public key to my api. But the post request fails with Timeout error. Following is my function for the request:

```
func perform<T: Decodable>(reqData: Data, with completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = reqData
    print("jsonData: ", String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "no body data")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let error = error else {
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        completion(try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data))
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

JSON Object sent in POST:

```
    {
  "publicKey" : "MIIBCgKCAQEA4lS13W+TXZhUXy5yB2NpeulCVb1ZSaReopeKrahjKmUx4NQxVXruEYCY3LpjZcSy8xiudVG3GBIMnPLtaMbc5WAYDj1M2OwnpNHdQ8SKtZ1tdA6iRjfOXGUa1n8FMIMKU5ynTSAiSoh+8gGrY0L6jTsCSdLO5ZU53LQFHSESM8JuBeNZozolb\/cKb38ylercVeVpo8egoA8UqHezK23VUJ23faxMmMZDJxVn5pfFedxBTLxwU65KQY8Z4izaFjuPLoGe5JZkXyYNMcrYloDCBG5m9BFiXVkoLEDmGFGfWLMJcqL+D2CszqJ4h712ZR6LYRNtIbo\/HG9KR7XCtap3QwIDAQAB"
}
```

I have tested the url in Postman and it works good there. But it is giving my follwoing error when I call it from my app:

```
    Task <6AB1B692-9CBF-4E37-80C6-4F37FD43264B>.<1> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x280299c50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <6AB1B692-9CBF-4E37-80C6-4F37FD43264B>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <6AB1B692-9CBF-4E37-80C6-4F37FD43264B>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.178.205:3000/savepublickey, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.178.205:3000/savepublickey, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
```

Following is my server side code in Node.js:

```
    app.post('/savepublickey', (req, res) => {
    console.log("savepublickey");
    console.log(req.body);
    let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));
    if (data['publicKey'] != null && data['publicKey'] != "") {
        console.log("Success");
        publicKey = data['publicKey'];
        res.status(200).json({
            "Status": "Success"
          }).send();
    } else {
        console.log("Fail");
        res.status(500).json({
            "Status": "Invalid request"
        }).send();
    }
})
```

Comment: Make sure the URL is correct. Aren't you missing some headers? e.g. `Accept`?

Comment: url is correct as same url works in Postman

Comment: Note, Apple requires `https`,  although 
you could temporarily change your `NSAppTransportSecurity` in your `Info.plist` to use `http`, 
for example using `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` or the more hazardous `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`